# backdrop cms module-created blocks deltas not working

Tags: module, drupal-7, block

(tagging with drupal7 because i cannot create a tag for backdrop)

i have a fresh backdrop install, with a new theme duped from bartik, and a new layout duped from moscone_flipped. no code changes to those yet.

i have a module that creates 2 simple blocks, mostly just some html. i have implemented hook_block_info() and hook_block_view(). i can place blocks into regions in the layout using the admin ui. i can see each block on the front end page when i place either one of them. but not both. when i have both blocks placed in the layout, for some reason both regions display the output from the same block. and i have verified that it is always the first block defined in the array returned from hook_block_info(). i have cleared caches, checked code, etc.

has anyone seen this before?

btw, i just applied the recent security upgrade, and the behavior is the same both before and after the upgrade.

i will paste in the module code below, in case i have missed something.

thanks for any help anyone can provide.

```
// implements hook_block_info()
function mbr_block_info()
{
  $info = array();
  $info['rate-tables'] = array(
    'info' => 'Rate Tables (Buttons)',
    'description' => 'The displays the rate table links for the sidebar',
  );
  $info['mbr-footer'] = array(
    'info' => 'MBR Footer',
    'description' => 'Displays footer links, disclaimer, copyright',
  );  
  return($info);
}

// implements hook_block_view()
function mbr_block_view($delta = '', $settings = array(), $contexts = array())
{
  $block = array();
  switch($delta)
  {
    case 'mbr-footer':
      $subject = null;
      $mbrFooter = getMBRFooterBlock();
      $block = array('subject' => $subject, 'content' => $mbrFooter);
    case 'rate-tables':
      $subject = null;
      $rateTables = getRateTablesBlock();
      $block = array('subject' => $subject, 'content' => $rateTables);
  }
  return($block);
}
```

Comment: nevermind, i found the issue. my bug in the code above: no "break" in the case statements. jeez, age is not my friend in this realm. :-)

Comment: Write an answer below with your findings